# Why won't my button move up no matter what I try?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move my back button in the upwards but no matter what I do, it doesn't work.

For example

- If I do `margin-bottom: 29%;`, then `Button One` and `Button Two` move down while the `back` button stays put and doesn't move.
- If I do `margin-top: 29%;`, then `Button One` and `Button Two` move down along with the `back` button.
- If I do `top: 29%`, the `back` button stays put and doesn't move.

How would I go about making my `back` button move up?

(If you need more code or need me to clear something up, please let me know)

```
.BackButton {
    border: 5px solid #401818;
    background: #a265d4;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#65d672), to(#a265d4));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #65d672, #a265d4);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #65d672, #a265d4);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65d672, #a265d4);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #65d672, #a265d4);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65d672 0%, #a265d4 100%);
    padding: 12px 8px;
    padding-right: 23px 46px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
    text-shadow: #bd7f7f 0 1px 0;
    color: #066b6b;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: helvetica, serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Can you post html and other button CSS code? We cant assume anything from given code as button might be dependent on other elements !

Comment: have you tried a negative margin-top and positive margin-bottom?

Comment: Move up how? If you need to move it around, you need position:absolute

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use position, for example:

```
.BackButton {
  postition: fixed; //can also use absolute
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
```

Enough you can do from there.

Comment: This solution might end up with a back-button covering the title in certain browsers and resolutions

Comment: @sp92 Changing _top: 0_ to something greater should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could try this on the back-button, as this will pull your element instead of adding to it.

```
margin-top: -29%;
```

It is more of a trick though than clean solution. I would actually suggest to put your back-button in the right order in the DOM as it is intended to be displayed, and then change the title question (h1/h2/h3) to *display: inline-block* and add padding to it the size of the backbutton to get the text centered correctly. If you use the trick you might end up with a button covering your title in certain resolutions and browsers.